# In Webpack, how to make root exported library a function?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, es6-modules

In Webpack I'm trying to figure out how to make the main exported object be a specific function rather than an object containing a function. What I'd really like is something like this:

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./app.js",
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist/",
        filename: "build.js",
        library: "App"
    }
};
```

app.js:

```
export default function Constructor(x, y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
```

app.html:

```
...
<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
<script>
    let x = 5; let y = 10;
    let app = new App(x, y);
</script>
...
```

But in reality this fails because `App` is not a function. Rather it's an object with a property of `default` that is the desired function. So I could do `new App.default(x, y)`, but that's ugly and feels unnecessary given that I only have a single entrypoint into my application's functionality.

There's got to be a cleaner way to do this, but I've not been able to figure it out, even in all [the other types of `libraryTarget`s](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[There is babel plugin for that](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports).

First, you need to install `babel-loader`, plugin and dependencies

```
npm i --save-dev babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-env babel-plugin-add-module-exports
```

Then, you need to add `babel-loader` and plugin in webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./app.js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env'],
                        plugins: [require('babel-plugin-add-module-exports')]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist/",
        filename: "build.js",
        library: "App"
    }
};
```

This works for simple one-file application in the question. However, `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` [is not without issues](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports/issues/39) and can be incompatible with more complex setup.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting approach. Ultimately, I would prefer a solution that doesn't require Babel in my build, though.